Enumerator attribute of parent class is initialized with String in child class - openapi-generator
I'm trying to generate the LeanIX Rest API SDK using the openapi-generator Gradle plugin.
There is a parent model that has a String attribute defined with an Enum:
    LxField:
      required:
        - type
      type: object
      properties:
        type:
          type: string
          enum:
            - StringValue
            - BooleanValue
            - IntegerValue
            - DoubleValue
            - DateValue
            - SingleSelect
            - Location
            - MultipleSelect
            - Lifecycle
            - ProjectStatusProgress
            - ExternalId
            - FactSheetReferencesFieldValue
            - SearchBasedFieldValue
      discriminator:
        propertyName: type

Other models inherit the previous model:
    DateValue:
      required:
        - type
      type: object
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/LxField'
        - type: object
          properties:
            value:
              type: string
              format: date

When generating the parent class, openapi-generator creates the Enum correctly:
public class LxField {
  /**
   * Gets or Sets type
   */
  @JsonAdapter(TypeEnum.Adapter.class)
  public enum TypeEnum {
    STRING_VALUE("StringValue"),
    
    BOOLEAN_VALUE("BooleanValue"),
    
    INTEGER_VALUE("IntegerValue"),
    
    DOUBLE_VALUE("DoubleValue"),
    
    DATE_VALUE("DateValue"),
    
    SINGLE_SELECT("SingleSelect"),
    
    LOCATION("Location"),
    
    MULTIPLE_SELECT("MultipleSelect"),
    
    LIFECYCLE("Lifecycle"),
    
    PROJECT_STATUS_PROGRESS("ProjectStatusProgress"),
    
    EXTERNAL_ID("ExternalId"),
    
    FACT_SHEET_REFERENCES_FIELD_VALUE("FactSheetReferencesFieldValue"),
    
    SEARCH_BASED_FIELD_VALUE("SearchBasedFieldValue");

    private String value;

    TypeEnum(String value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
      return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return String.valueOf(value);
    }

    public static TypeEnum fromValue(String value) {
      for (TypeEnum b : TypeEnum.values()) {
        if (b.value.equals(value)) {
          return b;
        }
      }
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected value '" + value + "'");
    }

    public static class Adapter extends TypeAdapter<TypeEnum> {
      @Override
      public void write(final JsonWriter jsonWriter, final TypeEnum enumeration) throws IOException {
        jsonWriter.value(enumeration.getValue());
      }

      @Override
      public TypeEnum read(final JsonReader jsonReader) throws IOException {
        String value =  jsonReader.nextString();
        return TypeEnum.fromValue(value);
      }
    }

    public static void validateJsonElement(JsonElement jsonElement) throws IOException {
      String value = jsonElement.getAsString();
      TypeEnum.fromValue(value);
    }
  }

  public static final String SERIALIZED_NAME_TYPE = "type";
  @SerializedName(SERIALIZED_NAME_TYPE)
  protected TypeEnum type;

  public LxField() {
  }

  public LxField type(TypeEnum type) {
    this.type = type;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get type
   * @return type
   */
  @jakarta.annotation.Nonnull
  public TypeEnum getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(TypeEnum type) {
    this.type = type;
  }



  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    LxField lxField = (LxField) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.type, lxField.type);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(type);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class LxField {\n");
    sb.append("    type: ").append(toIndentedString(type)).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
   * (except the first line).
   */
  private String toIndentedString(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
  }


  public static HashSet<String> openapiFields;
  public static HashSet<String> openapiRequiredFields;

  static {
    // a set of all properties/fields (JSON key names)
    openapiFields = new HashSet<String>();
    openapiFields.add("type");

    // a set of required properties/fields (JSON key names)
    openapiRequiredFields = new HashSet<String>();
    openapiRequiredFields.add("type");
  }

  /**
   * Validates the JSON Element and throws an exception if issues found
   *
   * @param jsonElement JSON Element
   * @throws IOException if the JSON Element is invalid with respect to LxField
   */
  public static void validateJsonElement(JsonElement jsonElement) throws IOException {
      if (jsonElement == null) {
        if (!LxField.openapiRequiredFields.isEmpty()) { // has required fields but JSON element is null
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("The required field(s) %s in LxField is not found in the empty JSON string", LxField.openapiRequiredFields.toString()));
        }
      }

      String discriminatorValue = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("type").getAsString();
      switch (discriminatorValue) {
        case "BooleanValue":
          BooleanValue.validateJsonElement(jsonElement);
          break;
        case "DateValue":
          DateValue.validateJsonElement(jsonElement);
          break;
        case "DoubleValue":
          DoubleValue.validateJsonElement(jsonElement);
          break;
        case "ExternalId":
          ExternalId.validateJsonElement(jsonElement);
          break;
        case "FactSheetReferencesFieldValue":
          FactSheetReferencesFieldValue.validateJsonElement(jsonElement);
          break;
        case "IntegerValue":
          IntegerValue.validateJsonElement(jsonElement);
          break;
        case "Lifecycle":
          Lifecycle.validateJsonElement(jsonElement);
          break;
        case "Location":
          Location.validateJsonElement(jsonElement);
          break;
        case "MultipleSelect":
          MultipleSelect.validateJsonElement(jsonElement);
          break;
        case "ProjectStatusProgress":
          ProjectStatusProgress.validateJsonElement(jsonElement);
          break;
        case "SearchBasedFieldValue":
          SearchBasedFieldValue.validateJsonElement(jsonElement);
          break;
        case "SingleSelect":
          SingleSelect.validateJsonElement(jsonElement);
          break;
        case "StringValue":
          StringValue.validateJsonElement(jsonElement);
          break;
        default:
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("The value of the `type` field `%s` does not match any key defined in the discriminator's mapping.", discriminatorValue));
      }
  }


  /**
   * Create an instance of LxField given an JSON string
   *
   * @param jsonString JSON string
   * @return An instance of LxField
   * @throws IOException if the JSON string is invalid with respect to LxField
   */
  public static LxField fromJson(String jsonString) throws IOException {
    return JSON.getGson().fromJson(jsonString, LxField.class);
  }

  /**
   * Convert an instance of LxField to an JSON string
   *
   * @return JSON string
   */
  public String toJson() {
    return JSON.getGson().toJson(this);
  }
}


However, the child class tries to initialize the "type" attribute using String:
public class DateValue extends LxField {
  public static final String SERIALIZED_NAME_VALUE = "value";
  @SerializedName(SERIALIZED_NAME_VALUE)
  private LocalDate value;

  public DateValue() {
    this.type = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
  }

  public DateValue value(LocalDate value) {
    this.value = value;
    return this;
  }
.
.
.

How can I solve this problem?
The complete API documentation is published at https://app.leanix.net/openapi-explorer/
The inherited attribute must be initialized with a value from the Enum.
